# Settings app crashes when opened from custom keyboard on iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, openurl

I'm trying to open Settings app from custom keyboard extension. It works fine on iOS 11, so the Settings app is being opened with main settings page. However, the Settings app immediately crashes on iOS 10 if it wasn't opened before (i.e. the app isn't in background). Have anybody encountered this problem?
Regards.

Comment: Are you able to see any logs?

Comment: @Sanket Bhavsar Only those from keyboard. There's no special logs from a Settings app which would explain the crash.